# Dismiss app extension after sending message

Tags: ios, ios-messages-extension

I would like to hide my app extension after sending a message. Is this possible?

I looked online and couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the viewController's dismiss() method. Not to be confused with dismiss(animated: completion:)